# Why can't I install packages in Emacs with package-install

Tags: emacs

Emacs version: 26.3, OS: Ubuntu 19.10

I have the following in init.el:

```
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
               '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (package-initialize)
```

If I open Emacs and do: `M-x packages-refresh-contents` it shows `connecting host: melpa...` and `package refresh done` in 1-2 secs.  If I proceed with: `M-x package-install <RET> <package>`, I always get: `no match`, but if I go to: `M-x package-list-packages` I can see the package and can install it via menu and it installs fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to clarify: you say you type `M-x package-install <package>` but you do hit `RET` (rather than `SPC`) between the two parts, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sequence is:
```M-x package-install```

```RET```

```<enter package>``` [No match]

Comment: It's better to clarify such details by editing the question, since comments may not always be visible.  As for your problem, FWIW, it sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup for package:

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa"))
     (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
     (setq package-check-signature nil)
     (setq use-package-verbose nil)
     (setq package-enable-at-startup t)
     (setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                              ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                              ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                              ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                              ("elpy" . "https://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/")))
 (package-initialize t)
```

I overwrite my package-archives variable (not sure what's in yours). I am setting a directory and some other stuff. Have you checked the output of your 'Messages' buffer?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I had too many configurations going. I created my *.emacs.d/* folder, but emacs had already created a *.emacs* file for itself in the home directory, and it was using that instead of the place where I had Melpa configured.

`rm ~/.emacs` fixed it for me.